# Why does when using Locks processes in python, a method can't run?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am working with threads in Python using Locks. My goal is to run simultaneously to objects Tracker and LocalMapper where it is supposed to send messages from the tracker object to the other. But, when I use Locks, the methods within with the Lock exists doesn't launch.

The program is :

```
import threading
import message_filters
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
import rospy

class Tracking:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mMutexReset=threading.Lock()

    def GrabImage(self,image_right,image_left):
        print("I am in grap image")
        self.call_mapping()
    def Run(self):

        print("Starting of the Tracking module ...")
        image_right = message_filters.Subscriber("/kitti/camera_color_right/image_raw", Image)
        image_left = message_filters.Subscriber("/kitti/camera_color_left/image_raw", Image)    
        ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([image_right,image_left], 10, 0.5)
        ts.registerCallback(self.GrabImage)
        #rospy.spin()

    def SetLocalMapper(self,LocalMapper):
        self.mpLocalMapper = LocalMapper;


    def call_mapping(self):
        self.mpLocalMapper.display()


class LocalMapping:

    def __init__(self):

        self.mlNewKeyFrames=[]
        self.mMutextester = threading.Lock()

        self.mbAcceptKeyFrames=True
        self.mlpRecentAddedMapPoints=[]


    def Run(self):
        self.mMutextester.acquire()       
        #print("here in the maping")
        r = rospy.Rate(500)  # 10hz
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            p=2
            #print("iam in mapping")
        self.mMutextester.release()
    def SetTracker(self,pTracker):
        self.mpTracker = pTracker

    def display(self):
        self.mMutextester.acquire()       
        print("display")
        self.mMutextester.release()       
if __name__=='__main__':
    rospy.init_node('neuronav')
    Tracker=Tracking();
    LocalMapper=LocalMapping()
    t_track = threading.Thread(target=Tracking.Run, args=(Tracker,))
    t_track.start()
    t_locl_map = threading.Thread(target=LocalMapping.Run, args=(LocalMapper,))
    t_locl_map.start()



    Tracker.SetLocalMapper(LocalMapper);
    LocalMapper.SetTracker(Tracker)
```

When I remove self.mMutextester from the display() function, it runs.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Younès

Comment: The whole point of a lock is to stop things from running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating a deadlock.

You *.acquire()* one place and then, somehow, are invoking another *.acquire()* (from within the same thread) before having released your lock. Thus the "nested" (re-entrant) call never completes and the lock is never released because it's waiting for a return that never happens.  (And, in this process, all other threads are eventually stalling on their attempts to acquire this lock).

Re-design your class/responsibility/collaboration (CRC) around thread coherent producer/consumer ***[Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)*** objects.  Feed work into your queues with some threads (producers), let other threads (consumers) take out each work object, perform work on it, and feed the resulting objects to an appropriate "reduce" queue where a single thread consumes them to post into your collected/aggregated results (potentially for batch processing in output or database writes, or whatever).

(I tried to glance through your code to see an obvious call/dependency loop ... but I couldn't spend much time on it and I get the impression that there's a bunch happening that I can't see from this code snippet).

I'm pretty suspicious of **LocalMapping.Run()** acquiring a lock, calling a ROS module **Rate()** function, and then holding the lock through a loop, before releasing it).  If the lock is to protect the ROS (robot?) from multiple threads changing its state (settings) then I think you need an object isolating that locking from your application's code ... again with some system to queue up operations performed on the robot to keep all access to it coherent.